# Using Nested Repeaters With Stored Procedures

Tags: asp.net, repeater

Hey I would like to use Nested Stored Procedures in ASP.NET 2.

The first stored procedure returns all Campains and second one returns all items in the campaigns.

I have my 2 repeaters set up, and now I am trying to pass a parameter from the parent repeater to child repeater stored procedure i.e campaign id....this proving tricky

In the code behind I wanted to try

```
public void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType ==
    ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.EditItem)
    {
        SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["campaignId"].DefaultValue =
            DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "campaignId").ToString();
    }

}
```

But I dont know how to call this method or get it to load if I try this

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnDataBinding="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
```

I get the error

CS0123: No overload for 'Repeater1_ItemDataBound' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Any help would be greatly appreciated

EDIT : Changed mY Code Behind to

```
public void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType ==
    ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.EditItem)
    {
        Response.Write(DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "campaignId").ToString());
        SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["campaignId"].DefaultValue =
            DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "campaignId").ToString();
        SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["statusId"].DefaultValue =
            "1";

    }

    foreach (RepeaterItem repeaterItem in Repeater1.Items)
    {
        ((Repeater)(repeaterItem.FindControl("Repeater2"))).DataBind();

    }

}
```

But no joy its passing the correct campaign id to the stored procedure but this isnt displayed correctly on front end

any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to attach the `DataBinding` event, you should be attaching the `ItemDataBound` event:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
```

The `DataBinding` event is for the whole repeater, the `ItemDataBound` will fire per item.

Comment: That fixed the error alright no joy..it doesn't seem to be binding the data correctly.

Comment: @StevieB - since your event handler isn't binding any data to a nested Repeater, I am not surprised.

Comment: @Oded ok I tried         SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["campaignId"].DefaultValue = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "campaignId").ToString();
        Repeater s = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("Repeater2");
        s.DataBind();

Comment: @StevieB - But where are you _databinding_ the nested repeater? I don't see you getting a reference to it or doing a bind on it.

Comment: @Oded Repeater 2 is the nested repeater, which you can see above i am databinding in the OnItemDataBound event

Comment: @StevieB - You are calling `bind`, but not setting a `DataSource` on it.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft publish an step by step guide to display hierarchical data using Nested Repeater Controls: [Display Hierarchical Data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/326338)

Remember that it is posible to return two datasets from a Store Procedure (An store procedure that ends with two SELECTs)

This is an example using EnterpriseLibrary

```
    Try
        Using cmd As DbCommand = db.GetStoredProcCommand("spYourStoreProcedure")
            db.AddInParameter(cmd, "@customer", DbType.Int32, nCustomer)
            Using ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(cmd)
                ds.Tables(0).TableName = "Parent"
                ds.Tables(1).TableName = "Child"
                ds.Relations.Add("MyRelation", ds.Tables("Parent").Columns("customer"), ds.Tables("Child").Columns("customer"))

                ParentRepeater.DataSource = ds.Tables("Parent")
                ParentRepeater.DataBind()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Manage your excepion
        Exit Sub
    End Try
```

This is a simple nested repeater:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="ParentRepeater" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <b><%# Container.DataItem("customer_name")%></b>
            <asp:Repeater ID="repFuncionesXArea" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Container.DataItem.Row.GetChildRows("MyRelation") %>' >
                <HeaderTemplate>
                   <ul>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li><%# Container.DataItem("customer_history")%></li>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    </ul>
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```